# Are the zones tie to particular authentication provider(s)?

Tags: authentication, alternate-access-mapping, web-application-zones

Are the zones tie to particular authentication provider(s)? or this is arbitrary?

Comment: Nope. You can have all the zones with NTLM with different url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you extended the web application to an additional site in IIS, that zone can be configured to have different authentication mechanisms.